# How can I get the location of a term or phrase in a chunk of text in a MS Sql 2008 Full Text index?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

Possibly related question: [How could I generate a contextual text extract from text returned from a SQL Server Full-Text Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588528/how-could-i-generate-a-contextual-text-extract-from-text-returned-from-a-sql-ser)

At any rate, I'd like to know if there is a way to get the position of the hit(s) within an indexed document. If this isn't possible, I was wondering if it's possible in any other full-text search technologies out there.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Derp. I just walked through the implications of the answer to that related question. If that's the best way then I guess it's the best way. Anyone have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end `sys.dm_fts_parser` appears to be the best/only solution to this. Unfortunately it seems to be able to only handle a maximum amount of characters so it's on to Lucene.NET for me.